# How does GHC know how to cache one function but not the others?

Tags: haskell, benchmarking, memoization

I'm reading Learn You a Haskell (loving it so far) and it teaches how to implement `elem` in terms of `foldl`, using a lambda. The lambda solution seemed a bit ugly to me so I tried to think of alternative implementations (all using `foldl`):

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import qualified Data.List as List

-- LYAH implementation
elem1 :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
y `elem1` ys = 
    foldl (\acc x -> if x == y then True else acc) False ys

-- When I thought about stripping duplicates from a list
-- the first thing that came to my mind was the mathematical set
elem2 :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
y `elem2` ys = 
    head $ Set.toList $ Set.fromList $ filter (==True) $ map (==y) ys

-- Then I discovered `nub` which seems to be highly optimized: 
elem3 :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
y `elem3` ys = 
    head $ List.nub $ filter (==True) $ map (==y) ys
```

I loaded these functions in GHCi and did `:set +s` and then evaluated a small benchmark:

```
3 `elem1` [1..1000000] --  => (0.24 secs, 160,075,192 bytes)
3 `elem2` [1..1000000] --  => (0.51 secs, 168,078,424 bytes)
3 `elem3` [1..1000000] --  => (0.01 secs, 77,272 bytes)
```

I then tried to do the same on a (much) bigger list:

```
3 `elem3` [1..10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000]
```

`elem1` and `elem2` took a very long time, while `elem3` was instantaneous (almost identical to the first benchmark).
I think this is because GHC knows that `3` is a member of `[1..1000000]`, and the big number I used in the second benchmark is bigger than `1000000`, hence `3` is also a member of `[1..bigNumber]` and GHC doesn't have to compute the expression at all.
But how is it able to automatically cache (or memoize, a term that Land of Lisp taught me) `elem3` but not the two other ones?

Comment: You'll notice that `elem3` gets slower and slower as `y` gets bigger, keeping `ys` the same.

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer**: this has nothing to do with caching, but the fact that you force Haskell in the first two implementations, to **iterate over all elements**.

No, this is because `foldl` works left to right, but it will thus keep iterating over the list until the list is exhausted.

Therefore you better **use `foldr`**. Here from the moment it finds a `3` it in the list, it will cut off the search.

This is because `foldr`is defined as:

```
foldr f z [x1, x2, x3] = f x1 (f x2 (f x3 z))
```

whereas `foldl` is implemented as:

```
foldl f z [x1, x2, x3] = f (f (f (f z) x1) x2) x3
```

Note that the outer `f` thus binds with `x3`, so that means `foldl` first so if due to laziness you do not evaluate the first operand, you still need to iterate to the end of the list.

If we implement the `foldl` and `foldr` version, we get:

```
y `elem1l` ys = foldl (\acc x -> if x == y then True else acc) False ys
y `elem1r` ys = foldr (\x acc -> if x == y then True else acc) False ys
```

We then get:

```
Prelude> 3 `elem1l` [1..1000000]
True
(0.25 secs, 112,067,000 bytes)
Prelude> 3 `elem1r` [1..1000000]
True
(0.03 secs, 68,128 bytes)
```

Stripping the duplicates from the list will not imrpove the efficiency. What here improves the efficiency is that you use `map`. `map` works left-to-right. Note furthermore that `nub` works lazy, so `nub` is here a *no op*, since you are only interested in the head, so Haskell does not need to perform memberchecks on the already seen elements.

The performance is almost identical:

```
Prelude List> 3 `elem3` [1..1000000]
True
(0.03 secs, 68,296 bytes)
```

In case you work with a `Set` however, you do not perform uniqueness lazily: you first fetch all the elements into the list, so again, you will iterate over *all* the elements, and not cut of the search after the first hit.

Answer (score 5):

### Explanation

`foldl` goes to the innermost element of the list, applies the computation, and does so again recursively to the result and the next innermost value of the list, and so on.

```
foldl f z [x1, x2, ..., xn] == (...((z `f` x1) `f` x2) `f`...) `f` xn
```

So in order to produce the result, it has to traverse all the list.

Conversely, in your function `elem3` as everything is lazy, nothing gets computed at all, until you call `head`.

But in order to compute that value, you just the first value of the (filtered) list, so you just need to go as far as `3` is encountered in your big list. which is very soon, so the list is not traversed. if you asked for the `1000000th` element, `eleme3` would probably perform as badly as the other ones.

### Lazyness

Lazyness ensure that your language is always composable : breaking a function into subfunction does not changes what is done.

What you are seeing *can* lead to a [space leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46007746/whats-a-space-leak) which is really about how control flow works in a lazy language. both in strict and in lazy, your code will decide what gets evaluated, but with a subtle difference :

- In a strict language, the builder of the function will choose, as it forces evaluation of its arguments: whoever *is called* is in charge.
- In a lazy language, the *consumer* of the function chooses. whoever *called* is in charge. It may choose to only evaluate the first element (by calling head), or every other element. All that *provided* its *own* caller choose to evaluate his own computation as well. there is a whole chain of command deciding what to do.

In that reading, your `foldl` based `elem` function uses that "inversion of control" in an essential way : `elem` gets asked to produce a value. `foldl` goes deep inside the list. if the first element if `y` then it return the trivial computation `True`. if not, it forwards the  *requests* to the *computation* `acc`. In other words, what you read as values `acc`, `x` or even `True`, are really placeholders for *computations*, which you receive and yield back. And indeed, `acc` may be some unbelievably complex computation (or divergent one like `undefined`), as long as you transfer control to the computation `True`, your caller will never see the existence of `acc`.

### foldr vs foldl vs foldl' VS speed

As suggested in another answer, **foldr** might best your intent on how to traverse the list, and will shield you away from space leaks (whereas **foldl'** will prevent space leaks as well if you *really* want to traverse the other way, which can lead to buildup of complex computations ... and can be very useful for [circular computation](https://wiki.haskell.org/Circular_programming) for instance).

But the *speed* issue is really an algorithmic one. There might be better data structure for set membership **if and only if** you know beforehand that you have a certain pattern of usage.

For instance, it might be useful to pay some upfront cost to have a `Set`, then have fast membership queries, but that is only useful if you know that you will have such a pattern where you have a few sets and lots of queries to those sets. Other data structure are optimal for other patterns, and it's interesting to note that from a API/specification/interface point of view, they are usually the same to the consumer. That's a general phenomena in any languages, and why many people love *abstract data types*/modules in programming.

Using `foldr` and expecting to be faster really encodes the assumption that, given your static knowledge of your future access pattern, the values you are likely to test membership of will sit at the beginning. Using `foldl` would be fine if you expect your values to be at the end of it.

Note that using foldl, you might construct the entire list, you do not construct the values *themselves*, until you need it of course, for instance to test for equality, as long as you have not found the searched element.