# Space leak in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, terminology, space-leak

In [Google's C++ test framework](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md#assertions), my eyes read:

> .. returns from the current function immediately, possibly skipping clean-up code that comes after it, it may cause a *space leak*.

while my brain expected to see a memory leak.

Is that terminology used in C++? If so, what does it mean (in other words how it's distinguishable from a memory leak)?

---

In [Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46007746/whats-a-space-leak), a space leak refers to a situation where a program or specific computation uses much more memory than is necessary.

In [Java](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/306226/does-it-make-sense-to-use-the-term-space-leak-with-regard-to-java), using the phrase "space leak" doesn't make sense.

Comment: I am really curious. Can you show us what code causes this issue?

Comment: I am curious too @dimoraichev, thanks for translating that into an upvote. I updated the question with a targeted link that leads exactly to the section googletest mentions that. It's doesn't really show code, but you I can imagine that it talks about a situation where the code dynamically allocates memory, then the assert fails, *before* the code has a chance to delete that memory. That's a classic scenario of a memory leak. I am wondering now whether my interpretation was correct, or whether the author used the wrong phrase... That's why I asked the question...

Comment: I suspect "resource leak" is probably the best wording for that paragraph.  Skipping cleanup code could result in leaking things other than memory (open file descriptors, HANDLEs, temp files, etc).  I don't think they mean anything special with the term "space leak".

Comment: That's a good idea @MilesBudnek, possibly eligible for an answer. After discussing it with the community here, maybe we could contribute there too, and make the wording used better.

Comment: With `Java` objects don't give up their memory until **every** reference to them dies. That means it is quite possible to inadvertently end up with unused objects that should have been deleted but weren't taking up space needlessly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a space leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46007746/whats-a-space-leak)

Comment: Isn't that the link I have already provided in my question @user1810087, which is specific to Haskell, whereas my question is about C++? :)

Comment: @gsamaras Yes it is :) . I did not meant to devalue your question, so it is a *possible* duplicate. And as you accepted the answer saying it is the same as in Haskell it is even more a duplicate. So, as a matter of fact...

Comment: Well, I think that @MilesBudnek comment is the answer user1810087, but I cannot mark a comment as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Space leak does not seem specific to a particular language. Wikipedia has this to say about [space leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak):

> A space leak occurs when a computer program uses more memory than necessary. **In contrast to memory leaks, where the leaked memory is never released, the memory consumed by a space leak is released, but later than expected.**

This is same as what it means in Haskell as per your cite.

Comment: But the two questions I linked to, show how it can change context between two languages. However, you answer the question about how it's different than a mem leak, +1.

Comment: @gsamaras: Is C++ more similar to Haskell or JAVA with respect to memory management? JAVA has garbage collection.

Comment: Interesting. I'd never heard this term used in the context of C++, though it does make sense.