# How can atomicModifyIORef cause leaks? And why does atomicModifyIORef' solve the problem?

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, functional-programming, atomic, ioref

If I search for `IORef a -> (a -> (a, b)) -> IO b` on [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/), the first result is

> #### [atomicModifyIORef :: IORef a -> (a -> (a, b)) -> IO b](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-IORef.html#v:atomicModifyIORef)
>
> ##### [base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base) [Data.IORef](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-IORef.html#v:atomicModifyIORef)
>
> Atomically modifies the contents of an `IORef`.
>
> This function is useful for using `IORef` in a safe way in a multithreaded program. If you only have one `IORef`, then using `atomicModifyIORef` to access and modify it will prevent race conditions.
>
> Extending the atomicity to multiple `IORefs` is problematic, so it is recommended that if you need to do anything more complicated then using `MVar` instead is a good idea.
>
> `atomicModifyIORef` does not apply the function strictly. This is important to know even if all you are doing is replacing the value. For example, this will leak memory:
>
> ```hs
> ref <- newIORef '1'
> forever $ atomicModifyIORef ref (\_ -> ('2', ()))
> ```
>
> Use `atomicModifyIORef'` or `atomicWriteIORef` to avoid this problem.
>
> This function imposes a memory barrier, preventing reordering; see Data.IORef#memmodel for details.

(I'm not sure why, if I click on any of the three links, the resulting doc page doesn't seem to contain the text *will leak memory*, which is contained in the excerpt above.)

The question is two folds:

- Why is the above example leaking memory?
- Why the leak doesn't happen if `atomicModifyIORef'` is used instead of `atomicModifyIORef`?

Comment: That's written in the text I quoted. If it was enough, I wouldn't have asked the question :D

Comment: It seems your question is not specific to `atomicModifyIORef`, but rather about lazy functions in general. If so, you might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46009036/15207568) useful.

Comment: As I understand it. atomicModifyIORef only guarantees that readIORef, modification and writeIORef will be done atomically. However, it does not guarantee that the new value will be forced. This means that the new value will be thunk. And if there is some sequence of such modifications, then these thunks will accumulate in memory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's run the code.

```
ref <- newIORef '1'
```

After this line, the contents of the IORef is just `'1'`.

Let's apply once this action:

```
atomicModifyIORef ref (\_ -> ('2', ()))
```

After this line, the contents of the IORef is `(\_ -> '2') '1'`.
Note that, because of laziness, this is *not* simplified to `'2'`, but is kept as an unevaluated thunk. (`atomicModifyIORef'` would instead simplify that.)

Once more, let's apply this action:

```
atomicModifyIORef ref (\_ -> ('2', ()))
```

Now the contents of the IORef is `(\_ -> '2') ((\_ -> '2') '1')`.

And so on, see the pattern? We build larger and larger unevaluated thunks, wasting memory, when we could (and should) simplify its contents.